# Android Push Notification Regsitration Id Validation

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I had set up the GCM notificaion in android .
with in one year i am getting so many device id for same device.
Is there any way to validate the Regsitraion id

I know on sending the push notification to old id it will gives the new id .
But i need to clear my Db is there any way to do it?

Comment: Every Launch of the application will not create a new Registration id. if the application is there is uninstalled and reinstalled then only sometimes new registration is will be created if the application is uninstalled tell me where to store the registraion id

Comment: i am storing it in server..... so again if the person updates the application or reinstals the application i cant update the application registration id because i dont know the old registration id

Comment: If already have the register id, store it to the local database or the sharedPreference. It helps to handle the registration.

Comment: if application is uninstalled the database and the sharedpreferences will be gone. i am talking about the reinstall of the application

Comment: It is not good to store IME number off all customers.thank you for your answer please check the bottom answer it will be usefull for you also

Comment: yes, it too helpful for me. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if you handle registration to GCM in the client side properly, you should be getting many registration IDs for the same device.

You should store the registration ID in the app's shared preferences, and register again to GCM only when a new version of your app is installed on the device (that's what Google recommend to do).

To handle the case of your app being uninstalled and installed again, you can generate a unique instance identifier for each device. Send that identifier to your server along with the registration ID. Store that identifier in the device's external storage, so it won't get deleted when your app is uninstalled. Try to restore it from external storage (if it's available) when your app is installed. Now, if you get a new registration ID, but still have the original instance identifier, when you send them to your server, your server will see it already has an old registration ID for that instance identifier, and will replace the old registration ID with the new one (instead of creating a new record).

Second of all, if you fail to avoid the creation of duplicate registration IDs for the same device in your DB, your only option to detect them is by sending a GCM message to the registration ID and handling the returned canonical registration ID. You could, however, send a message with `dry_run=true`, which simulates the sending of a message without actually sending it. I just tested it with an old registration ID. The message wasn't delivered, but I got the response with the canonical registration ID.

> **dry_run**    If included, allows developers to test their request without actually sending a message. Optional. The default value is false.

Comment: thanks for your answer . This can be implemented in the new build but now my db is full of multiple registraion id of the same device is there any other way like ping for these registration id . with out sending push notification.Is there any method to validate with google?

Comment: is that parameter to be included in headers ?

Comment: @user3559065 No, it's not part of the header. It's part of the request (either url-encoded or JSON, depending on what you are using).

Comment: {
  "registration_ids" : ["regid"],
  
  
  "data" :  { "message":"This is a test message"}
}
i am sending like this

Comment: @user3559065 So try to add it to the end of the JSON - ... "data" : { "message":"This is a test message"}, "dry_run":"true"}. I only tested the URL encoded version, so I'm not sure exactly how it should look like with JSON. Either "dry_run":"true", "dry_run":true, "dry_run":"1" or "dry_run":1 should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer it is workking fine{
  "registration_ids" : ["registration_id"],
  
  
  "data" :  { "message":"This is a test message"},"dry_run":true
}